# How can I create a dynamic return type based on a varargs of enum values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, variadic-tuple-types

What I'm trying to accomplish is having a function that takes in a variable number of a certain enum, then returns an object whose keys are equal to the provided values and whose values are typed to those found in a type map. The problem can be demonstrated from this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar',
    Baz = 'baz'
}

interface TypeMap {
    [MyEnum.Foo]: { foo: string };
    [MyEnum.Bar]: { bar: string };
    [MyEnum.Baz]: { baz: string };
}

type MyFunctionResult <T extends Array<MyEnum>> = {
    [key in T]: TypeMap[key];
};

const myFunction = <T extends Array<MyEnum>> (...keys: T): MyFunctionResult<T> => {
    const result: MyFunctionResult<T> = {} as any;
    for (const key of keys) {
        switch (key) {
            case MyEnum.Foo:
                result.foo = { foo: "foo"};
                break;
            case MyEnum.Bar:
                result.bar = { bar: "bar"};
                break;
            case MyEnum.Baz:
                result.baz = { baz: "baz"};
                break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

const test = myFunction(MyEnum.Foo, MyEnum.Bar); //Expected: should have keys 'foo' and 'bar'
const foo = test[MyEnum.Foo]; //Should have type of Foo
const bar = test[MyEnum.Bar]; //Should have type of Bar
const baz = test[MyEnum.Baz]; //Should show an error, as this property should not exist
```

Instead, I'm getting back a type of `any`. Is there some way of accomplishing what I'm after?

It's come to my attention that the above, while "working" in IDEA, fails to parse in the Typescript Playground. After playing around in the playground, I've changed the following from the above:

```
type MyFunctionResult <T extends keyof TypeMap> = {
    [key in T]: TypeMap[key];
};

const myFunction = <T extends keyof TypeMap> (...keys: T[]): MyFunctionResult<T> => {
    const result = {} as any;
```

This works fine in the playground but IDEA is complaining with: `Argument type MyEnum.Bar is not assignable to parameter type MyEnum.Foo`. It's seeming like this may be an IDEA-specific issue, but I'm not sure if there's something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I see other errors in a Playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) before you get to the last few lines, did you try fixing those?

Comment: Interesting @jonrsharpe -- I was using IntelliJ IDEA and it doesn't have the same complaints. I'll see if I have any better luck in the playground, but I still just don't know how to structure the typing to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: So I've actually managed to get it working in the playground, but IDEA complains about it.

It's very possible I've tried this before and I guess maybe it's an IDEA-specific problem (I'm using IDEA 2020.1.4 and Typescript version 4.0.3, but in the playground it works at least as far back as 3.5), unless there's something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Then please [edit] with a [mre] of wherever you got to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, was in the middle of doing that. I've added an edit that hopefully explains it -- I wasn't sure if it was better to show the diff or update the whole example, especially since it seems the nature of my problem may have changed.

Comment: The latter, update to ask the question you have now - people can always look in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64884959/timeline if they want to see how the post evolved, but will largely only care about the most recent version. It's only useful to stop making big changes once you have *answers*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224702/discussion-between-apropos-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

My previous answer was bad. I don't know what I was thinking about :D

Here you have working example:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar',
  Baz = 'baz'
}

interface TypeMap {
  [MyEnum.Foo]: { foo: string };
  [MyEnum.Bar]: { bar: string };
  [MyEnum.Baz]: { baz: string };
}

type ToRecord<
  T extends string[],
  Cache extends Record<string, number> = {}
  > = (T extends []
    ? Cache
    : T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? (Head extends string
      ? (Tail extends string[] ? ToRecord<Tail, Cache & Record<Head, string>>
        : never)
      : never)
    : never)

type Result = ToRecord<[MyEnum.Foo, MyEnum.Baz]>

// and here
const myFunction = <Key extends MyEnum, Keys extends Key[]>(...keys: [...Keys]) =>
  keys.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: elem
  }), {} as ToRecord<Keys>)

const test = myFunction(MyEnum.Foo);
const foo = test[MyEnum.Foo]; // ok
const bar = test[MyEnum.Bar]; // expected error
const baz = test[MyEnum.Baz]; // expected error
```

**`ToRecord`** - iterates recursively throught the tuple and converts it to the object. It works almost like `myFunction`. Algorithms almost the same except `ToRecord` runs recursively.